# Get all available items between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

i am having difficulties with one query, so i need to select all available attendants between two dates, and i have tables like this

```
attendant { 
id,
name
}

job {
id,
attendantId,
name,
startDate,
endDate
}
```

What i need to do is to get ALL available attendants that don't have any job in period between 2 dates.

I'am trying to accomplish that with this query, but from some reason i don't get attendants that are not busy between provided dates

```
SELECT a.id, a.firstName, a.lastName, a.phoneNumber, a.address, a.attendantType
FROM attendant a
WHERE a.id NOT IN  (
SELECT attendantId FROM job
WHERE startDate <= PROVIDED_END_DATE AND endDate >= PROVIDED_START_DATE
)
```

For example if i have job for atteendant John Doe, that runs from 1.1.2017 to 1.10.2017 and if i select to get all available attendants from 1.11.2017 to 1.15.2017 i need to retrun John Doe as available attendant, and if for example i select that i need available attendants from 1.09.2017 to 1.15.2017 i should not get John Doe because obviously he is busy in that period (on 1.09. and 1.10). So long story short i need to return attendants that are not in job table for selected period.

With my current query i have issues because when NOT IN clause returns 0 rows i don't get other attendants.

This is example from my database, i have one job that looks like this:

```
Job {
attendantId: 1,
startDate: 2017-05-01,
endDate: 2017-05-06
}
```

and my query looks like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.firstName, a.lastName, a.phoneNumber, a.address, a.attendantType
FROM attendant a

WHERE a.id NOT IN  (

SELECT c.attendantId FROM job j

WHERE j.startDate <= "2017-05-24" AND j.endDate >= "2017-05-20"

)
```

and i'm expecting attendant with id 1 to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is close. Hopefully the following will work for you:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.firstName,
    a.lastName,
    a.phoneNumber,
    a.address,
    a.attendantType
FROM attendant a
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT c.attendantId
                FROM job j
                WHERE j.startDate <= "2017-05-24"
                  AND j.endDate >= "2017-05-20"
                  AND a.id = c.attendantId
                )
```

Comment: Do you have idea why this don't work when i add OR, like this
```WHERE 
startDate <= '2017-05-15' AND endDate >= '2017-05-13' 
OR startDate <= '2017-05-17' AND endDate >= '2017-05-13' AND a.id = attendantId``` , because i want to check dates with some offset

Comment: Make sure you have brackets to ensure all the parts are evaluated​ in the order you are expecting.

Comment: I tried to add brackets but probably i did it on wrong way, can you show me please ?

Comment: I reckon you want: `WHERE 
((startDate <= '2017-05-15' AND endDate >= '2017-05-13')
OR (startDate <= '2017-05-17' AND endDate >= '2017-05-13')) AND a.id = attendantId`

Comment: My comment assumes you're after an attendant who is available in BOTH date ranges. If you really wanted for them to be available in EITHER date range then I'd go for `Where Not exists (select ...) Or Not exists (select ... )`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select * from attendant
inner join 
(select attendantId from job where PROVIDED_START_DATE > endDate or PROVIDED_END_DATE < startDate) t
on
attendant.id = t.attendantId
```

Comment: Wrong results, i realized that my query is "fine" but from some reason when NOT IN clause returns 0 rows i can't get attendants it look like it only works when not in returns TRUE, any way to fix that ?

Comment: Can you show me your `PROVIDED_START_DATE `, `PROVIDED_END_DATE` and wrong record's startDate and endDate ?

Comment: @SuperMario'sYoshi - I see your edited question, I put dates into query.  So, this not works for you: `select attendant.* from attendant
 inner join 
 (select attendantId from job where '2017-05-20' > endDate or '2017-05-24' < startDate) t
 on
 attendant.id = t.attendantId`